# QuantLib: Which CalibrationHelper to use for Normal Volatilities

Tags: quantlib, calibration, swaption

I am using the SwaptionHelper class to create the swaptions.

Reading the documentation: https://www.quantlib.org/reference/class_quant_lib_1_1_swaption_helper.html

I realize that one of the parameters required to provide is called BlackCalibrationHelper. However, I am using Normal volatility for the calibration.

I think it is also not possible to just omit the parameter.

Could anyone advise the parameter to provide in this case? The example online used CalibrationHelper which is deprecated in v1.16.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `SwaptionHelper` class inherits from `BlackCalibrationHelper` class:
https://www.quantlib.org/reference/class_quant_lib_1_1_black_calibration_helper.html
As a result, one of its attributes is `volatilityType` which can be normal or lognormal or shifted lognormal.

You can see it in the first constructor in the link you sent:

```
SwaptionHelper (
   const Period &maturity, const Period &length,
   const Handle< Quote > &volatility,
   const ext::shared_ptr< IborIndex > &index,
   const Period &fixedLegTenor,
   const DayCounter &fixedLegDayCounter,
   const DayCounter &floatingLegDayCounter,
   const Handle< YieldTermStructure > &termStructure,
   BlackCalibrationHelper::CalibrationErrorType errorType=BlackCalibrationHelper::RelativePriceError,
   const Real strike=Null< Real >(), const Real nominal=1.0,
   const VolatilityType type=ShiftedLognormal, const Real shift=0.0)
```

As you can see, by default it is `ShiftedLognormal`, but you can set it to `Normal` when instanciating your swaption helper.

Comment: thanks, I have seen that, I guess my question was more around the blackcalibrationhelper class. are we using blackcalibrationhelper class even though we are using normal vol to construct the swaption?

Comment: The answer is yes, `SwaptionHelper` is a subclass of `BlackCalibrationHelper` (which handles the three vol types).

Comment: The `CapHelper` doesn't accept Volatility type, does it? Is it not possible to calibrate to caps with normal vols as input?

Comment: It seems that's not the case: https://github.com/lballabio/QuantLib/blob/82d303a02900842ec897865c727d43f11ed7d4f5/ql/pricingengines/capfloor/blackcapfloorengine.cpp#L62-L66 However, I'd recommend to ask the question on QuantLib's mailing list. I also stumbled upon this case https://github.com/lballabio/quantlib/issues/38 it is closed but is seems only the `shiftedLognormal` case was done.